# It's possible to transfer a string from an Background Task to the Main Program UWP?

Tags: c#, sockets, xaml, uwp

I'm developing an application with a background task that runs every time I receive data via a socket. I'm using the StreamSocketListener function from Microsoft.

I would like to recover in my main program the string received by my background task to be able to perform actions.

How can I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put content in the Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings from the background task and then check the setting from the app on a periodic basis.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use named pipes for interprocess communication, you find more information in the documentation
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-use-named-pipes-for-network-interprocess-communication